# Периодическая проверка подключения устройства с использованием таймера

Tags: c#, события, таймер, xamarin.forms

Нужно реализовать постоянную проверку состояния подключения устройства с некоторым интервалом времени. То есть, есть таймер с заданным временем, по истечению которого должна происходить проверка подключения. Была попытка реализовать это следующим образом: в `OnAppearing` создаётся таймер, к которому добавлен обработчик события `Elapsed`:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

В обработчике события происходит следующая проверка:

```
    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var drivers = FindAllDrivers(usbManager);
        var driver = drivers.Where(d => d.Device.VendorId == DEVICE_VENDOR_ID && d.Device.ProductId == DEVICE_PRODUCT_ID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (driver == null)
        {
            // Здесь происходит обновления визуала приложения
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectToDevice();
            // Здесь так же происходит обновления визуала приложения
        }
    }
```

Но я столкнулся с проблемой того, что постоянное возникновение события не позволяет нормально выполняться коду внутри тела if/else. Каким образом стоит решить эту проблему?

Comment: стопайте таймер в начале метода `Timer_Elapsed` и перезапускайте в конце.

Comment: Подумал, что Ваша идея решит проблему, но попробовав, обнаружил, что не помогло.

Comment: значит вот это ваше предположение неверно `постоянное возникновение события не позволяет нормально выполняться коду внутри тела if/else`

Comment: Таймер по истечению времени вызывает этот же метод, не дожидаясь его окончания. Метод не успевает выполниться.

Comment: Это невозможно, если вы стопанули таймер в нечале метода. Если таймер все ещё вызывает метод, значит он не остановлен, значит вы не сделали того, что я посоветовал.

Comment: Да, верно. Попробовал снова и заработало. Благодарю.

Comment: На здоровье. Хорошо, что завелось.